# If statement not working with between dates

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following if statement:

```
$current=date('d/m/Y');
$next_year=date('y')+1;

$q1a='01/04/'.date('Y');
$q1b='30/06/'.date('Y');

$q2a='01/07/'.date('Y');
$q2b='30/09/'.date('Y');

$q3a='01/09/'.date('Y');
$q3b='31/12/'.date('Y');

$q4a='01/01/20'.$next_year;
$q4b='31/03/20'.$next_year;

if (($current > $q1a) && ($current < $q1b)) 
{ 
    $currentquarter='Q1'; 
} 
elseif (($current > $q2a) && ($current < $q2b)) 
{ 
    $currentquarter='Q2'; 
} 
elseif (($current > $q3a) && ($current < $q3b)) 
{ 
    $currentquarter='Q3'; 
}
elseif (($current > $q4a) && ($current < $q4b))
{ 
    $currentquarter='Q4';
}   

echo $currentquarter;
```

BUT its returning Q1 even though it should be Q3 as todays date falls between 01/09/2017 and 31/12/2017

Comment: You can't compare d/m/Y date strings using `<`, `>`, etc. Either use a format that will work with basic comparison operators (timestamps or Y-m-d), or use proper `DateTime` objects.

Comment: Your variable are strings. They cannot be compared to date objects. First convert them to Date objects. Check [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: Sidenote: why `'20' . date('y') + 1` instead of `date('Y') + 1`? This code is hardcoded to assume being executed after 2010 and before 2100; which is probably a safe-enough assumption, but still a terrible habit when dealing with dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not comparing *dates*, you're lexically comparing *strings*. E.g.:

```
'21/03/2017' > '01/04/2017'
```

`2` is larger than `0`, so this will be true. Character by character the first string sorts "larger than" the second. Again, it's a *lexical* comparison, not a *numeric* comparison.

At the very least you need to reverse the endianness to `Y/m/d` to get the correct result; but you should really construct `DateTime` objects or UNIX timestamps to do actual date/numeric comparisons properly.

Answer (score 2):

For date comparison in PHP you can use `strtotime()` function

```
$date1    = '07/28/2018';
$date2    = '07/28/2017';

if(strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2))
{
    echo 'Date2 is greater then date1';
}
else
{
    echo 'Date1 is greater then date2';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would help you simplify the comparison to retrieve the current quarter.

```
function CurrentQuarter(){
     $n = date('n');
     if($n < 4){
          return "1";
     } elseif($n > 3 && $n <7){
          return "2";
     } elseif($n >6 && $n < 10){
          return "3";
     } elseif($n >9){
          return "4";
     }
}
```

[Code Source](https://smileyhappycoder.co.uk/server-side/get-the-current-quarter-number-with-php/)